# Firefox: Date/time variable for about:config settings

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I auto-export Firefox bookmarks as my way of backing them up. This occurs every time I quit Firefox.

This is done like so, in `about:config`:

- `browser.bookmarks.file` enabled
- Extra entry `browser.bookmarks.file` set to the likes of `/Users/myusername/Dropbox/Upload/bookmarks.html`

My question is: is there a way to automatically insert the date inside of that path? I'd like to export in the form of `YYMMDDhhmm-bookmarks.html` where YYMMDDhhmm is the date/time.

Comment: Could you instead write a script that you use to launch Firefox instead of launching it directly from its shorcut? The script, which you could write as a bat file, powershell, bash, python, whatever could copy and rename the file and then launch firefox. Keep in mind that dropbox also keeps some set of past file revisions.